# Creating a Drop Down List in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I'm not an MVC expert. In my view (.cshtml file), I have a Model that I'm binding to. In my model, I have a list of `short` values setup like this:

```
public void Load() {
  List<short> options = new List<short>();
  options.Add(1);
  options.Add(3);
  options.Add(7);
  this.Options = options;
}

public List<short> Options = new List<short>() { get; set; }
public short? SelectedOption = null;
```

In my .cshtml file, I need to let the user choose one of the options from a drop down list. I see a bunch of HTML helpers, but I'm totally confused how to do this. How do I just display the drop down list and bind it back to my model? I am successfully binding to text boxes already, so I know I have my plumbing setup correctly. Its just this drop down list that's throwing me for a loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the object you are passing to the .cshtml view is your list which can be either passed through the `ViewBag` or as `model`. 

Then depending in your requirement you can use multiple things to make a dropdown list out of which most preferable would be.
`Html.DropDownList` extention. [Link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx)
so typical code would be

```
var options = Model ; //OR Viewbag.Options;
@Html.DropDownList(options.Select(o=>
  new SelectListItem()
{
   Text = o.ToString(), 
   Value = o.ToString()}
))
```

Also if you want to do it without any such specialized helper then
you can just create the HTML yourself.

```
<select>
@foreach(var o in Options){
<option value="@o.ToString()">@o.ToString()</option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Small working snippet:

```
@model SelectListItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;

    List<SelectListItem> x = new List<SelectListItem>() 
    { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "100", Selected = false },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "200", Selected = true }
    };
}

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Text, x)
</body>
</html>

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Above is the code of a view. You can pass a full model from the controller, when calling the View method, that will contain the list of elements you want to show. For the example, I simply created it on the fly (x list)

Comment: The 1st parameter to the DropDownListFor method is a property selector lambda expression - the property you select here is the one which will be displayed in the select options (much like setting the "DataTextField" in a non-mvc (web forms) ASP.NET DropDownList.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way for a dropdownlist..

In your controller

```
      var sample = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "0" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "2" } };
      ViewBag.something = sample;
```

In your View,

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.colname, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.something , null, new { type = "text", Class = "", style = "" })
```